# Extremely simple factory contract works on testrpc/ganache-cli but not rinkeby

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation, rinkeby

this very simple factory pattern is not working on rinkeby for some reason. Using truffle `v3.4.5` and geth `1.7.3-stable`. Here are the contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Factory {

  address[] public pizzas;

  function Factory() {
    // constructor
  }

  function cookPizza() returns (address _pizza) {
    Pizza newPizza = new Pizza();
    pizzas.push(newPizza);
    return newPizza;
  }

  function getPizzas() public constant returns (address[]) {
    return pizzas;
  }
}

contract Pizza {
  function Pizza() {
    // constructor
  }
}
```

When I deploy on ganache-cli and run:

```
truffle(development)> Factory.deployed().then(function(instance) { factory = instance})
undefined
truffle(development)> factory.cookPizza()
truffle(development)> factory.getPizzas()
[ '0xc4f8cf2d5a37e74981fffdab1b2108931822359a' ]
```

It creates a new address, appends and `getPizzas` shows me the addresses. When I deploy on rinkeby with the following:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  Migrations: 0x42e40188763019dd09a6166b76805d329bd71111
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying Factory...
  Factory: 0xb9d60d9ddf16e3af3bce774a1e9286ecf5614166
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
```

In the console:

```
> sender = eth.accounts[0]
> abi = "abi"
> contract = eth.contract(abi)
> factory = contract.at("0xb9d60d9ddf16e3af3bce774a1e9286ecf5614166")
> factory.cookPizza({from:sender})
"0xf0ce6f4c0a9665f593d3d837eca4977b85d011dcb3620bf3a2428d25225db967"
> factory.getPizzas()
[]
```

Nothing. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is your contract abi equal to "abi" or you did this just to simplify?

Comment: It's simplified :)

Comment: how did you start your console?

Comment: `geth attach ipc:/Users/mokn1/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc`

Comment: and how did you start your rinkeby node? are you using light version? If yes, it is not sync the states

Comment: `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi web3,db,personal,eth,net`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your transaction and it failed. https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xf0ce6f4c0a9665f593d3d837eca4977b85d011dcb3620bf3a2428d25225db967

That´s why getPizzas() is returning an empty array.

Add funds to account[0] and unlock it and try again. It should work.

Comment: My account has 23 eth https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xfc7846d06fab273c62cda0d29eac0936a22eeca4. Are you able to interact with the contract?

Comment: Yes. I tried Remix and it worked. My local Rinkeby node is not sync and I will have to wait until I can use geth console to interact with your contract. Did you unlock your account before calling cookPizza()?

Comment: Yes, it's unlocked. The tx goes through but is failing.

Comment: my last suggestion would be increase gas. 
factory.cookPizza({from:sender ,   gas: 3000000 })

Comment: That worked! I had the default gas at 2000000.. should have been enough?

Comment: Weird.. my `truffle.js` file has the following: ```rinkeby: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "4",
      from: "0xfc7846d06fab273c62cda0d29eac0936a22eeca4",
      gas: 2000000```

It should work..

Comment: Good! But your gaslimit was not 2.000.000. It was 90.000. You open the transaction that has failed and you can check the field "gas limit". It is 90.000. Geth has a default value. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e61035c5a3630e4f6fd0fb3e5346a4eed8cedc80/internal/ethapi/api.go#L50

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69210/discussion-between-michael-orourke-and-luiz-soares).